# Android eclipse OnClickListener working with OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, eclipse

i want to validate if the spinner equal "something" then it will toast a text "please pick a value" .The validation triggers whenever we click the button.

the problem is i don't know how to implement it properly.However i made a code to do that and the toast text will appear when we do nothing,when the app launched the toast text just appear without click on the button. And other validations works perfectly it will appear after we click(checking if edittext empty)

EDIT:i'm making a PMT function app where there are an edittext for price input, another for percentage of the price.And then there are some spinner for picking if the thing you re buying(in my app its for counting the price for cars) is new or used, zone you re living(in my country there are 3 zones Mid,East,West)and the insurance(combine,comprehensive,TLO).Those all will then be calculated when the button clicked, but to avoid bug i want to have a validation which will triggered by the same button.And this where i got stuck, my code is bad in structure, i mean my implementation is bad

i want to do something like this one:

```
String item1,item2;
Textview result;

result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View seletedItem, int pos, long id)
       {
          /*if an item selected it will give a value to the spinner item that is selected to be calculate along with edittext values and other spinners and if nothing selected or the spinner item is equal to the hint on the spinner(in this case, suppose that as"please pick something")(this hint on xml i put as item <item>-please pick something-</item><!--hint-->)then it will toast a text "please pick something pls pls" and <---this text will be triggered when we click the button, take a look at public void count(this one is the button(android:OnClick="count"))*/ 
         //suppose it will be item1 here
       }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {

        }
});

spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
{

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View selectedItem, int pos, long id)
        {
           //same thing as the 1st spinner
           //suppose it will be item2 here
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {

        }
    });spin3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
{
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View selectedItem, int pos, long id)
        {
           //same thing as the 1st spinner
           //suppose it will be item3 here
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {

        }
    });
}    
public void count(View v)
{
    if(item1.equals("Hello") && item2.equals("World")&&item3.equals("2015"))
    {
        //do the calculation
        //put the result o0n table
        Intent intent=new Intent(Mastercode.this,TableOutput.class);
                    startActivity(intent);//it will go to next activity
    }
    else if(item1.equals("please pick one from the list as this spinner will show") {
        Toast.makeText(this, "you might want to pick something first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();return;
    }
}
```

if the user pick something from spinner list,where each item on the list have some value(in this case its a percentage for increasing the price,in PMT(PMT of my institution(company) where i'm now having internship there) condition,insurance and zone will affect the price) then it will calculate the 1st payment, permonth payment and so on and then put this 1st payment, payment permonth thing to a table on that new activity^^^^for code above^^^^

here is my code:

```
        public void thebutton(view v){
        int N1 = 0, N2 = 0, N3 = 0, N4 = 0, N5 = 0;
        int U1 = 0, U2 = 0, U3 = 0, U4 = 0, U5 = 0;
        double EffectiveRate = 0.12;
        String ethint2 = ethint1.getText().toString();
            String etpersen3 =etpersen2.getText().toString();
            spikon.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
            {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View seletedItem, int pos, long id)
               {
                  String item1 = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);              
                //set value change
                else if(item1.equals("-Please pick something about blablabla1-")){
                  Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Please pick something about blablabla1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  return;
              }

               }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                {

                }
             });

            spias.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
            {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View selectedItem, int pos, long id)
                {
                   String item2 = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                 //set value change         
                      else if(item2.equals("-Please pick something about blablabla2-")){
                      Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Please pick something about blablabla1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      return;
                  }              
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                {

                }
            });

            spizon.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
            {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View selectedItem, int pos, long id)
                {
                   String item3 = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);    
                   //set value change
                    else if(item3.equals("-Please pick something about blablabla3-")){
                      Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Please pick something about blablabla3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      return;
                  }

                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                {

                }
            });

            if(ethint2.trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "please fill the price", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            else if(etpersen3.trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "please fill the percentage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }                                     
           }
```

the xml code for thebutton of the layout

```
<Button

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:onClick="thebutton"
            android:text="@string/calculate"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
```

my previous code before"here is my code":

```
package com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Mastercode extends Activity implements TextWatcher ,AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    EditText ethint1, etpersen2, textvDP1;
    Spinner spinner,spinner1,spinner2,spikon,spias,spizon;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simulasikredit);
        ethint1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ethint);
        etpersen2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpersen);     
        textvDP1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textvDP);
        spikon = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerkondisi);
        spias = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerasuransi);
        spizon = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerzonawilayah);
        spikon.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
            {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View seletedItem, int pos, long id)
               {
                  String item1 = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);              
                //set value change
               }
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                {
                }
             });
            spias.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
            {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View selectedItem, int pos, long id)
                {
                   String item2 = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)        }
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                {}
            });
            spizon.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
            {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View selectedItem, int pos, long id)
                {
                   String item3 = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);             
                }
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                {
                }
            });     
        etpersen2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String text1 = ethint1.getText().toString();
                String text2 = etpersen2.getText().toString();
                int input1 = 0;
                int input2 = 0;
                if(text1.length()>0)
                      input1 = Integer.valueOf(text1);
                if(text2.length()>0)
                      input2 = Integer.valueOf(text2);                
                if (text1.length() != 0) {    
                    int output = (input1 * input2) / 100;
                    textvDP1.setText(""+output);}
                else if(text2.length() == 0){
                    textvDP1.setText("");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });                     
    }              
                public void delete(View v) {                     
                       ethint1.setText("");
                       etpersen2.setText("");
                       textvDP1.setText("");
                      }
                public void startcalculateandvalidate(View v){
                    String ethint2 = ethint1.getText().toString();
                    String etpersen3 =etpersen2.getText().toString();
                    if(ethint2.trim().equals("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill the price", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    else if(etpersen3.trim().equals("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill the percentage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    else if/* i want to check the value of spinners here with more else if, then toast the text.but it wont work , when i use this code---> elseif(item1.equals("please pick something")){Toast} the item1 will be red underlined with "item1 cannot be resolved to a variable" while its on spikon.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()*/
                    else
                    {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(Mastercode.this,TableOutput.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }}
                     public void makeDecimal(View v){  }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int count, int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
                }
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
                }
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }                                                               
}
```

Comment: where calling `thebutton` method?

Comment: i put it on OnCreate ,i ll update. Edit:But its from .xml layout, android:Onclick="thebutton". that whole code inside thebutton is the method,inst it?

Comment: btw, why people with high reputation like to downvote other's post.

Comment: @ george samuel : you can see my down-vote rate i never down-vote any question which is very clear

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK : i didn't refer that to you ,just wondering. Need at least 125 rep to downvote , 125 rep its high for me

Comment: please update more code where calling `thebutton`

Comment: You should remove parts of the code not important with the issue (replacing the `onItemSelected` body with a comment for example). As is this question is unclear because we don't have much context. You might also want to properly indent this code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK  i'm still new to java and android. I didn't get the point.Please give an example. thanks in advance

Comment: @RC. i'm still new to java and android. I didn't get the point.Please give an example. thanks in advance [duplicate comment]

Comment: url or reply or anything

Comment: I think (probably as ρяσѕρєяK think) you are calling `button()` somewhere in your activity to setup the `ItemSelectedListener` on the `spikon`

Comment: @georgesamuel: please show full code of Activity in which you are currently using `thebutton` method

Comment: i ll update more explanation , a sec

Comment: i updated codes,explanations

Answer (score 1):

Toast is shown every time your activity is created because, every time an activity is created the spinner is instantiated with its data and you must be seeing a value every time on the spinner for example 0 incase your data is (0,1,2,3...). So the spinner sets this value and the **OnItemSelectedListener** is called.

To avoid this, set the first value of your spinner as "select data" or something like that and in OnItemSelectedListener put a check

```
if("select data"){
//do nothing
}
```

you can check if something is selected or not by this as well:

```
int check = 0;

     yourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) 
            {
               if(check>0)
               {
               //Toast showing selected item value
                      Toast.makeText(parentView.getContext(),"OnItemSelectedListener : " +  parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               check+=1;

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(topThis, "nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: if it solves your problem..do check this answer as correct..thank you, have a good day :)

Comment: edit:my spinners have first value "Please pick something " on each spinner ,i want to validate if the user haven't pick anything or pick "Please pick something"  again the app will remind the user with toast text and say"Please pick something please please i'm begging or something "

Comment: your idea is to set a value on each item of the spinner(s) have,isn't it? that's a good idea, i'll keep in mind. but my problem is not solved just yet

Comment: if user doesn't change the selection from "Please pick something " to any other value, nothing will happen. If the user will select "Please pick something " again it will show the toast. If the user will select any other option, the respective else if option will work.

Comment: what exactly is your problem.

Comment: edit: i need the validation to toast on both situation(when the user doesnt change the selection and when the user will select "Please pick something " again).Could you implement it or give an url that have that code. i got the idea but i dont know how to implement it properly

Comment: when i run the app it will toast the text even before i do anything(like selecting item from spinner(s) or fill the edittext).I'am looking for validate this using button, link the spinner onitemselected with button. You might want to see my code(s) and explanation above

Comment: whenever your activity is created for first time. The spinner selects "Please pick something " as its item and so the onItemSelected is called on its own. So you should implement if else in onItemSelected :
 if "Please pick something " do nothing, else Toast.

Comment: is there a way to call OnItemSelected when the user click/hit the button and preventing it from calling itself whenever we start the activity?

Comment: yes...check the answer, using "int check=0"..have edited it again